# Have Class<T extends { [key: string]: any }> implement T

Tags: typescript

I have an injectable `Class<T extends { [key: string]: any }>` which has the purpose of obtaining a Generic Object. Such as:

```
interface Home {
  darkTheme: boolean;
  userType: number;
}
```

and then I would inject my class like:

```
constructor(myClass: Class<Home>) {}
```

this works great for some methods that live inside my class. However, I want the class to be aware that its body has the keys of T as properties also. In a way that this:

```
const userType = this.myClass.userType // acknowledges it exists
```

is ok by typescript.

TS doesn't throw an error with this, and `userType` would get the desired value. But this happens with Typescript being ignorant that the property exists in the body of `myClass`.

**So how can I tell Typescript that `myClass<T>` has a body `T`?**

I have tried:

```
class myClass<T extends { [key: string extends keyof T]: any}> // nope

class myClass<T extends { [key: string]: any } implements/ extends T> // also nope

// I tried overloading
interface myClass<T extends { [key: string]: any }> {
  [key: K keyof T]: T[K]; // don't know what 'K' is;
}

interface myClass<T extends { [key: string]: any }> {
  [key: keyof T]: T[keyof T]; // interfaces don't like mapped types
}
```

and little more. If you have any idea how can I achieve this, or if it's possible at all, I'd be happy to read you! :D thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript does not support extending the type parameter directly. Depending on what you are trying to do, you can either use a type alias:

```
type Class<T> = T & {}
declare let myClass: Class<Home>
myClass.userType // works, and is checked
myClass.userTypes // err
```

Or you can define your class without the explicit `T` and then cast it as a constructor that returns something that also has the properties of `T`:

```
class _Class { 
    m() { }
}

const Class = _Class as (new <T>() => _Class & T);  
type Class<T> = T & _Class
let myClass = new Class<Home>()
myClass.m(); //ok
myClass.darkTheme // ok
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is the right way, but I fail to make it work. Could you expand (please) on the const declaration on the second code you added? this line `const Class = _Class as (new <T>() => _Class & T);` confuses me. Am I declaring a constant typescript class through the use of const?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli The class at  run-time is just a function callable with the `new` operator. We can take a defined class and assign it to a variable and use the variable going forward without any issues. In this case we do this so we can change the type of the object returned by this constructor.